Childhood Cartoon Featuring A Small Blue Bird
So, I used to absolutely adore this animated movie when I was a kid. I owned it on VHS and I assume it was made somewhere in the early or mid 1990's. The film was about a small, blue colored bird. It took place in a city and I can distinctly remember the bird residing within some sort of hole in the top of a building as well as flying about the city. Sadly, these are the only memories I have of the film. I no longer own the VHS tape and my many searches online have come up empty. If anyone could provide me with the title of this film and, if possible, a little more information about it my nostalgia and I would be very grateful.

This sounds a lot like the animated film, Willy the Sparrow.  The movie is about a young boy who, after shooting birds with his BB gun, is turned into a sparrow by the "Sparrow Guardian."  He has a somewhat blue color to him (especially if your VHS had some distortion on it) and is taught how to fly by another sparrow, named Ciper. In return, Willy teaches Ciper to read.
The birds reside in the city, and fly around it often.  Willy has a nest in an attic, and once Ciper teaches Willy how to fly in the attic, they leave through a propped up vent/window.
The film was made in Hungary and was released in 1989. It had much critical acclaim, and an English adaptation was also release.
